# "Contents" for multiple levels?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm aware that "content" should be used for uncountable entities and measured concentrations, but does this also apply to multiple different concentrations?

E.g.

> The glucose and sulfate contents were low.

or

> The glucose and sulfate content was low.

(I would just use "levels", but the word content is used throughout this lengthy document and I rather not replace it each time.)

Comment: Are you talking about two different contents (a glucose content and a sulfate content), or are you talking about a single content (containing both glucose and sulfate)?

Comment: this refers to a series of different concentrations (that of compound x, that of compound y, etc.), otherwise it would be clear.

Comment: I don't know exactly how "concentration" relates to "content", but it seems to me that either one could be correct. As far as grammar is concerned, both are certainly correct.

Comment: If this is short for "the glucose content and sulfate content were both low", then "contents" would be correct. They're two separate contents being measured.